# AWS IAM Identity Center Configuration using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform. I was experimenting with AWS IAM Identity Center, but could not find a solution.

Context - I have a directory service - example.com and Active Directory on EC2 (domain join completed) with my users and groups.(Achieved this with terraform till this point). Now I want to bring those users and groups into the AWS IAM Identity center and create new permission sets and assign them to the AWS accounts.

Goal - I want to setup and configure AWS IAM Identity Center, and work on the importing/sync of users and groups from the AWS directory service and create permission sets and assign them to the account, all with terraform.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not clear what you are asking.  Some portions of AWS IAM Identity Center, as far as I have been able to discover in the past, appear to be console-only operations that cannot be automated with Terraform (or any other tool, including aws-cli) because there do not appear to be any documented, external-facing APIs for these actions; however, as this question now stands, I am uncertain whether your issue is with this, or with something else.  Please update the question, mentioning specific sub-tasks that you can't complete, and explain, in detail, where you are stuck.

Comment: Looks like James Z has made the edits please feel free to let me know if the objective is not clear.

To answer your question Micheal, i want to bring the users and groups from the active directory to the Identity center, and assign them to the AWS accounts at hand. All of this using terraform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automate the configuration of the identity source and user provisioning via Terraform (currently).

Once you configure that manually, you can use Terraform to provision Permission Sets and Account Assignments.

Comment: Can you point me towards a Terraform documentation, which I can refer to provision permission sets and Account Assignment.

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_permission_set May help you?

Comment: @ShinigamiSinofWrath To fully answer your question, provisioning users and groups can be done via SCIM to populate users and groups in Identity center but local AD does not natively support SCIM so you will need to use a 3rd party tool to enable that. Once that is done you can use terraform to provision permission sets and account assignments. I have an example in my branch here: https://github.com/tschmidty69/terraform-aws-sso/blob/ts-changes/examples/tschmidt/main.tf

Answer (score 7):

As of writing this answer on 4 Jan 2024, there are currently limited operations that we can perform using Terraform. Unfortunately, if you want to set up the AWS SSO ( IAM Identity Center ), you must start the process manually using the **ClickOps** (aka AWS Console) approach. To do so, you will need to follow the steps below:

1. Login to your root admin account
2. Select primary region
3. Go to **IAM Identity Center (successor to AWS Single Sign-On)**
4. Click on the orange **Enable** button

From there on, you will be able to use Terraform to setup the following resources:

1. AWS SSO Admin

- [aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_account_assignment)
- [aws_ssoadmin_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_application)
- [aws_ssoadmin_application_assignment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_application_assignment)
- [aws_ssoadmin_application_assignment_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_application_assignment_configuration)
- [aws_ssoadmin_customer_managed_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_customer_managed_policy_attachment)
- [aws_ssoadmin_instance_access_control_attributes](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_instance_access_control_attributes)
- [aws_ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment)
- [aws_ssoadmin_permission_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_permission_set)
- [aws_ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy)
- [aws_ssoadmin_permissions_boundary_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_permissions_boundary_attachment)
- [aws_ssoadmin_trusted_token_issuer](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssoadmin_trusted_token_issuer)

2. AWS SSO Identity Store

- [aws_identitystore_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/identitystore_group)
- [aws_identitystore_group_membership](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/identitystore_group_membership)
- [aws_identitystore_user](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/identitystore_user)

Comment: Thanks Petar for the suggestions, really appreciate it.